# How do I persist data in custom table in Magento Database (the right way)?

Tags: magento2, service-contract

I have created a module that adds a custom table.

I also created a Model, ResourceModel and Collection classes, and was able to use them to insert data into this new table by calling the ModelFactory class and saving (`save()`) the data.

But I am wondering if this is the best practice or if I should create Api interfaces for doing that, or/and using [Service Contract](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html) even if I don't want this class in Magento API.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1. Resource Model for CRUD operations
2. Model/ModelInterface for Data Modeling
3. Repository/RepositoryInterface as frontend for database operations
4. Custom table

Technically, you don't need interfaces but it is best practice and there is a reason behind it.